# How to define combined Strings in resources?

Tags: java, android

I have the below String defined in XML file

```
<string name="Url_Google">https://google.com</string>
```

to get the value of Url_Google dynamically, I can use

```
Toast.makeText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.Url_Google), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Now, I have two Strings in **ActivitySample.java** file

```
String One = "Url";
String Two = "Google";

String Three = One + "_" + Two;
```

The value for **String Three** would be **Url_Google**

How can I fetch the String value of Url_Google in XML file using the **String Three**

Edit: My apologies. The last statement was unclear. I don't want to edit the value of String defined in XML file. I simply want to fetch the value of Url_Google from XML file using the String "Url_Google"

Thanks

Comment: I wonder what is such need?

Comment: @Wizard, Well, there are some 20 Url stored in XML file. Also, the value of **String Three** will always be an Instance in XML file one of the defining 20 Urls. I was just wondering if the above method be used to find the Url String from XML file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this..may solve your problem

```
 public static String byValueName(Context context, String name) {
    Resources res = context.getResources();
    return res.getString(res.getIdentifier(name, "string", context.getPackageName()));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the official Android Documentation you can use the method:
[`getIdentifier`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

> **getIdentifier**
>
> `int getIdentifier (String name, 
>                   String defType, 
>                   String defPackage)`
>
> Return a resource identifier for the given resource name. A fully
>   qualified resource name is of the form "package:type/entry". The first
>   two components (package and type) are optional if defType and
>   defPackage, respectively, are specified here.
>
> Note: use of this function is discouraged. It is much more efficient
>   to retrieve resources by identifier than by name.
>
> Parameters name   String: The name of the desired resource.
>
> `defType`     `String`: Optional default resource type to find, if "type/" is
>   not included in the name. Can be null to require an explicit type.
>
> `defPackage`  String: Optional default package to find, if "package:" is
>   not included in the name. Can be null to require an explicit package.
>
> Returns int   int The associated resource identifier. Returns 0 if no
>   such resource was found. (0 is not a valid resource ID.)

So use `getIdentifier()` to find the resource `id` of `Url_Google` and then pass this `id` to `getResources().getString(id)`

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("Url_Google", "string", YourActivity.this.getPackageName())
```

Comment: Must be the recommended answer. Provides a better explanation that the accepted answer. Saw your answer bit late :(

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
<string name="one">Url</string>
<string name="two">Google</string>
<string name="Url_Google">%1$s_%2$s</string>
```

and then

```
Toast.makeText(this,
           String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.Url_Google),
                         getResources().getString(R.string.one), 
                         getResources().getString(R.string.two)), 
           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: I don't want to edit the value of the String defined in XML file. I simply want to fetch the value of Url_Google from XML file using the concatenated String "Url_Google". So is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change/add a Resource in runtime. To be precise, you cannot modify anything in the `res` folder in runtime so you either add it to the `strings.xml` as you already did, or there is no way you can achieve it with a programmatically defined String as you presented

Answer (score 1):

You can not modify resources data programmatically. When your application compiled, `aapt` will generate R class, which contains resource IDs for all the resources in your res/ directory. For each type of resource, there is an R subclass (for example, R.drawable for all drawable resources), and for each resource of that type, there is a static integer (for example,  R.drawable.icon). This integer is the resource ID that you can use to retrieve your resource.

So, You can not update resource programmatically.

Alternative,

You can use `Sharedprefrence` as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

**Try like this**

```
    String One = "Url";
    String Two = "Google";

    String Three = One + "_" + Two;

    int String_id = getResources().getIdentifier(Three, "string", BrowserMainActivity.this.getPackageName());

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String_id, 0).show();
```